# How to use a restored graph while training the current graph

Tags: tensorflow, graph, restore, training-data

I'm currently working on complex models (too complex for my weak brain) and I begin with tensorflow in the same time.

```
def load_model():
     checkpoint = tf.train.latest_checkpoint('my_checkpoint')
     new_graph = tf.Graph() #the one that we need to restore

     with tf.Session(graph=new_graph) as sess:
         saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(checkpoint + '.meta')
         saver.restore(sess, checkpoint)

     print("Model restored")
     return graph_seg
```

So, this is my function to load the previously saved and trained model. 
Apparently, it seems to work fine and to load the operations that I need.

Now, I want to create my main model :

```
def create_main_model(X,Y):
    with tf.name_scope("G_on_real"):
        with tf.variable_scope("G"):
            Y_channels = int(Y.get_shape()[-1])
            fake_Y = create_generator(X, Y_channels)

    #Blablah, we define all the things that we need.

    loaded_graph = load_model()

    with loaded_graph.as_default():
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            results = sess.run(fake_Y) # Trick here !
```

The thing is that I want to be able to use **fake_Y** as an input of the loaded model. **fake_Y** is generated at each step during the training phase. With the obtained output, I want to compute a new loss and integrate it in the total loss of my main model.

I know that **fake_Y** doesn't exist in the graph **loaded_graph**. And tensorflow returns me this error :

```
ValueError: Fetch argument <tf.Tensor 'G_on_real/G/decoder/deconv_3/Tanh:0' shape=(1, 128, 128, 3) dtype=float32> cannot be interpreted as a Tensor. (Tensor Tensor("G_on_real/G/decoder/deconv_3/Tanh:0", shape=(1, 128, 128, 3), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.)
```

So I think my problem is really basic. I just need to find a way to connect these two graphs. But the tensorflow's workflow is not super clear in my mind.

In the easier case of two disconnected graphs, I could just call **sess.run** on **fake_Y**. But here, it's not possible since I'm still building my main model, so I can't call a session with a bunch of things not initialized yet.

So, is there a way to share **fake_Y** between my two graphs (one initialized and the other one not) ?

Any help would be appreciated !
Thank you

EDIT: I've found a solution to load the model directly inside the current graph (then I don't need to create a new graph anymore). I don't know which solution is the best. But anyway, the problem remains the same : How to run the loaded/initialized model (which share the current graph with the main one) on **fake_Y** : a call to sess.run in the function in which we build the model is pretty weird and not feasible since some objects are not initialized yet.

Answer (score 0):

The right solution is to load the new model inside your current graph.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
 

Thank for your answer ! Do you know why is it the right solution ? Instinctively, I would say that is better to use 2 separate graphs because it provides an independence between my two models.

What about the call at the loaded model with sess.run(fake_Y). The problem if I do this, is that during the call of the function create_main_model I'll try to run the loaded and initialized model while the main model is not initialized yet. So it returns me an "Attempting to use uninitialized value".

Thank you !

Comment: A single Tensorflow session can only run operations from a single graph, regardless of how many models are in the graph. So if you want to use them together they need to be in the same graph. The uninitialized value message is there because not all variables are loading. Maybe initialize and then load?

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

So as suggested above. I initialized and loaded my model. Then, the code looks like :

```
with tf.variable_scope("segmentation_model"):
    seg_model = create_previous_model(X, Y)

checkpoint_seg = tf.train.latest_checkpoint('my_checkpoint')
restore_variables = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope="segmentation_model")
restore_variables_keys = [x.name.replace('segmentation_model/', '').replace(':0', '') for x in restore_variables]
dict_restore_variables = dict(zip(restore_variables_keys, restore_variables))

saver = tf.train.Saver(dict_restore_variables)
with tf.Session() as sess_seg:
    saver.restore(sess_seg, checkpoint_seg)
```

So I create the previous model which has no weights yet. It will contains the future loaded model when I'll call **saver.restore**. Note that the loaded model has been trained with different X and Y, but it doesn't matter, right ?

The thing is that my main model, and the model I want to load have the same variables. So I have to create the model I want to load in a specific scope, then use a dictionnary to load the model in the right scope.

In my main model, I have this line :

```
seg_model = load_segmentation_model(X,Y) #which do the job described above
output_seg_model = seg_models.outputs

#Few lines to define losses and other tensors of the main model.
```

I have checked that the model was effectively loaded by printing the variables included in "segmentation_model" scope. Everything seems OK.

Tensorflow doesn't return any errors. But when I display the output of the loaded model (which is an image), the image seems to have been generated (I'm working on generative models) by a non-trained generator. And in fact, the output remains the same when I don't call **saver.restore**. So the call is useless but doesn't return any errors :'(

Do I miss something obvious ?

Thank you !!

Comment: Ok, I figured out where does my problem come from. It comes from a call to apply_gradients in the function create_previous_model. This call, when used in a variable_scope, creates tensors with a wrong name. I'm gonna fix this. Thank you Alexandre!